# How to get from Trieste to Rijeka in the morning, and back in the evening?

Tags: italy, buses, car-rentals, croatia, day-trips

I am making travel plans for May 2023 and will be spending some days in Trieste.

I would like to make a day trip from there to Rijeka, probably on a weekday (the most likely candidate is the 8th of May). I was unable to find any good information about ways to get to Rijeka in the morning and back to Trieste in the evening. For example, there seem to be no results when I search on the Flixbus website or some other bus operators' websites.

I would prefer to go by bus if one is available. I also have an EU driving license, so I could rent a car if there are no buses, but also do not know if there is a good place to rent a car that would be open at such early/late hours that I would be able to spend most of the day in Rijeka. (I also do not have any experience with renting cars, so information about how far ahead I would have to plan that is welcome too.)

Is there a good way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I suspect the bus schedules have simply not been loaded yet for the dates of your proposed trip. I see options if I search FlixBus next week (more choices on weekends, but still some on weekdays). Try searching again when your trip is closer and see what you find.

Comment: @mlc Thank you, that is indeed helpful. I can reproduce your results and will try doing exactly what you suggest.

Comment: It takes five hours plus by train so I would avoid that for a day trip.

Comment: @mdewey which is an average velocity of about 15 km/h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if when you asked the question the schedule was not loaded yet as @mlc suggests, but now I can find quite a good option on the filxbus site.
[here Trieste -> Rijeka](https://shop.global.flixbus.com/search?departureCity=40de9f2f-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&arrivalCity=40e11860-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&route=Trieste-Rijeka&rideDate=08.05.2023&adult=1&_locale=en&features%5Bfeature.darken_page%5D=1&features%5Bfeature.enable_distribusion%5D=1&features%5Bfeature.train_cities_only%5D=0&features%5Bfeature.webc_search_persistent_explore_map%5D=0&atb_pdid=93a79144-0d8f-4367-b39d-d2ba9a426390&_sp=0be1c86a-71f7-4ad4-9f49-837f3ea69647&_spnuid=0ea19e6c-5413-478e-bc24-58e46cb099f2) and [here Rijeka -> Trieste](https://shop.global.flixbus.com/search?departureCity=40e11860-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&arrivalCity=40de9f2f-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&route=Rijeka-Trieste&rideDate=08.05.2023&adult=1&_locale=en&features%5Bfeature.darken_page%5D=1&features%5Bfeature.enable_distribusion%5D=1&features%5Bfeature.train_cities_only%5D=0&features%5Bfeature.webc_search_persistent_explore_map%5D=0&atb_pdid=93a79144-0d8f-4367-b39d-d2ba9a426390&_sp=0be1c86a-71f7-4ad4-9f49-837f3ea69647&_spnuid=0ea19e6c-5413-478e-bc24-58e46cb099f2) for a daytrip.